# how to link to a file with spaces in the filename in github README.md

Tags: git, markdown

I have a repository A in github, and there is a folder B, and a file named "hello world.md" in folder B. (There is space in the filename.)

In the README.md in repository A, I want to link to "hello world.md", so I write in this way:
`[hello world](./B/hello world.md)` or `[hello world](./B/hello\ world.md)`
but they all cannot work. How to link the file correctly?

Comment: **Avoid files paths with spaces inside**. Prefer the underscore `_` or the dash `-` to space, so rename `hello world.md` as `hello-world.md`. Filenames with spaces are always diificult to handle (both for you and your users or partners), so please don't have any. Since you are using [github](http://github.com/) you can discipline yourself to have decent file names and paths.

Comment: Use `git mv` to rename a [git](http://git-scm.com/) controlled file. With a Unix shell you'll need to use some [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) in that command.

Comment: BTW you also want to avoid brackets and parenthesis in file paths for MarkDown text.

Answer (score 44):

Basile Starynkevitch is right, we should avoid use spaces, brackets and parenthesis in file paths both for us and others. But if there are cases that we cannot avoid spaces, we can use `%20` to replace the space in the link path, then it will work.

Comment: … except Jekyll (for GH Pages) breaks that and ignores things with `%20` in the links…